# How to send a text message using the Twilio API

Tags: python, twilio

I am working on a Python project to send a text message to a specific phone number. The code below should load the api credentials into the Twilio REST client then send a message to `RECIPIENT`.

```
# Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install
from email import message
import os
from twilio.rest import Client
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import logging
import os
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# Set environment variables
ACCOUNT_SID         = os.getenv("ACCOUNT_SID")
AUTH_TOKEN          = os.getenv("AUTH_TOKEN")
PHONE               = os.getenv("PHONE")
RECIPIENT           = os.getenv("RECIPIENT")

# Load environment variables
load_dotenv()

accountSID   = ACCOUNT_SID
authToken    = AUTH_TOKEN
myNumber     = RECIPIENT
twilioNumber = PHONE
twilioCli = Client(accountSID,authToken)
messages = twilioCli.messages.create(body="The boring task is finished",from_=twilioNumber, to=myNumber)

logging.debug(f"{message.sid}")
```

Expected:
The message should be sent and the message SID should be printed out.

Actual:

```
File "C:\Users\EvanGertis\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\twilio\rest\__init__.py", line 58, in __init__
    raise TwilioException("Credentials are required to create a TwilioClient")
twilio.base.exceptions.TwilioException: Credentials are required to create a TwilioClient
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the: # Load environment variables is below your assignments, put it at thr top before assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Look at that "# Set environment variables" section,

Try to put these in things

```
    ACCOUNT_SID         = os.getenv("# Put your account Sid here")
    AUTH_TOKEN          = os.getenv("# your auth token here")
    PHONE               = os.getenv("# your phone you registered on twilio")
    RECIPIENT           = os.getenv("# the number you got from twilio")
```

this will help you to run the code &
if this doesn't work then there a trick:

look at the "# Load environment variables" section,

Try to put these in things

```
     accountSID   = # Put your account Sid here
     authToken    = # your auth token here
     myNumber     = # your phone you registered on twilio
     twilioNumber = # the number you got from twilio
```

Comment: No, these values do _not_ go in those strings. [`os.getenv()`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.getenv) loads an [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). For example, you might use `ACCOUNT_SID = os.getenv("ACCOUNT_SID")` (literally using the string `"ACCOUNT_SID"`) to retrieve the value of the `ACCOUNT_SID` environment variable. Setting that value happens _outside of_ your Python code. There are many ways to do it, depending on the situation: `.env` files and tooling in development, Heroku config vars, OS-level settings, etc.

Comment: (The whole point of putting configuration into environment variables in the first place is so you don't have to hard-code it, so you can avoid leaking sensitive info like passwords, and so you can vary it from environment to environment.)